# Python Pandas Set Value in DataFrame where Index has Multiple Identical Label Values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to set a value in a row in a pandas dataframe where the row index has duplicate values and the value of a date column is the max value for the selected index value.

My dataframe:

```
Index  Start_Date   End_Date   

  A      2017-10-01   2017-10-13
  B      2017-10-07   2017-10-15
  B      2017-10-18    np.Nat
  C      2017-10-09   2017-10-30
```

so I want to set the End_Date for `index` value 'B' where the `Start_Date` is the `Max` for 'B'

What is the best way to do this?

EDIT:

My dataframe:

```
Index  Start_Date   End_Date   

  A      2017-10-01   2017-10-13
  B      2017-10-07   2017-10-15
  B      2017-10-18    np.Nat
  C      2017-10-09   2017-10-30
  D      2017-11-01    np.Nat
  E      2017-11-03   2017-11-09
  E      2017-11-13    np.Nat
```

Through separate processes I come to learn that the End_Date corresponding to row #3 (Index == 'B', Start_Date == '2017-10-18 is 2017-10-25.  I also separately find that row #5(Index == 'D', Start_Date == '2017-11-01'  is 2017-11-03.  So I want to fill those values into End_Date one at a time.  Since I don't have an End_Date value for the last row (Index = 'E', Start_Date == '2017-11-13') that will stay empty.

Note that 'D' is unique while 'B' is not.

Output:

My dataframe:

```
Index  Start_Date   End_Date   

  A      2017-10-01   2017-10-13
  B      2017-10-07   2017-10-15
  B      2017-10-18   2017-10-25
  C      2017-10-09   2017-10-30
  D      2017-11-01   2017-11-03
  E      2017-11-03   2017-11-09
  E      2017-11-13    np.Nat
```

Not that the values 2017-10-25 in row 3 and 2017-11-03 came from another process and we can assume they are stored in variables - that can then be used to populate the initial dataframe to obtain the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

`df = df.reset_index()` removes the label as index and gives me a numerical index with unique values

```
Index     Item       Start_Date   End_Date   

  0          A      2017-10-01   2017-10-13
  1          B      2017-10-07   2017-10-15
  2          B      2017-10-18    np.Nat
  3          C      2017-10-09   2017-10-30
  4          D      2017-11-01    np.Nat
  5          E      2017-11-03   2017-11-09
  6          E      2017-11-13    np.Nat
```

`idx_val = df[df['Item'] == item][-1:].index.values[0]`

gives me the index value of the `item` I provide with the maximum `Start_Date`.

So if I have an `End_Date` value of '2017-10-25' for `item` 'B' coming from my other process, I get the index of the row with the max `Start_Date` for `item` B by using the above line of code.  If `item` == `B`, `idx_val` will equal 2.

I then simply set `End_Date` for the row where `idx_val` == 2:

`df.loc[idx_val, 'End_Date'] = pd.to_datetime('2017-10-25')`

and the result is:

```
Index     Item       Start_Date   End_Date   

  0          A      2017-10-01   2017-10-13
  1          B      2017-10-07   2017-10-15
  2          B      2017-10-18   2017-10-25
  3          C      2017-10-09   2017-10-30
  4          D      2017-11-01    np.Nat
  5          E      2017-11-03   2017-11-09
  6          E      2017-11-13    np.Nat
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting the datetime format

```
df.End_Date=pd.to_datetime(df.End_Date,errors='coerce')
df.Start_Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Start_Date)
```

Then we do `apply` + `fillna`

```
df['End_Date']=df.groupby('Index').apply(lambda x : x['End_Date'].fillna(x['Start_Date'].max())).values
df
Out[277]: 
  Index Start_Date   End_Date
0     A 2017-10-01 2017-10-13
1     B 2017-10-07 2017-10-15
2     B 2017-10-18 2017-10-18
3     C 2017-10-09 2017-10-30
```

Comment: Thanks.  Could you break your solution down a bit and explain?  Want to ge sure I follow.

Comment: @Windstorm1981 groupby the index, as you stated you want using B's max value, then we doing fillna by using B's max Start_Date to the B's End_Date group by group

Comment: Trying to fill selected values.  Not all.  Is there a suggestion on how to perhaps use set_values?  I think your solution is on target but not trying to fill all empty cells,

Comment: @Windstorm1981 my method will fill all NaT value , so you only want to fill some of them ?

Comment: Yes.  correct.  So I may have a single End_Date for one Group.  I just want to fill that value.

Comment: @Windstorm1981 you can add drop duplicate in the end df=df.drop_duplicates('Index')

Comment: I'm not clear on how that solves the problem.  Also, if I separately have a unique index value where I'm trying to fill the end date, I think that will throw an error.

Comment: @Windstorm1981 can you show the case you mentioned (input data)? You can update it in your question

Comment: @Windstorm1981 where is the 2017-10-25 come from ?

Comment: 2017-10-25 and 2017-11-03 come from another process.  I have those values.  Now I want to populate them in the appropriate place in the dataframe.

Comment: @Windstorm1981 is that the same question ? .............since you did not provide all the information ...I can not help ..

Comment: Yes - it's the same question!  I have values.  I'm trying to populate the dataframe.  Some observations have a duplicate index and some don't!!

Comment: @Windstorm1981 where is the value from another process? and where is your expected out put ?

Comment: ok - lets say that variable b_date = '2017-10-25' and variable d_date = '2017-11-03'.  I want to set `df.loc['D','End_Date'] = d_date`.  Easy enough.  But 'B' is not unique.  So I'm not sure of the syntax.  I can't use df.loc['B','End_Date'] = d_date because there are multiple rows with that address.  And I'm trying to figure out the syntax whether the index values are unique or not (which is wy answer 2 doesn't work - it only works where the index values are non-unique).  Thanks.  I will edit expected out put now so hopefully that is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

```
# get the row indexes
row_idx = df.sort_values(['Index', 'Start_Date']).duplicated(keep='last')

# set values
df.loc[row_idx, 'End_Date'] = 'Your desired value'
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks.  Follow on question.  If the index value for which I'm trying to fill an 'End_Date'  is unique, with the use of `duplicated` throw an error or will it simply process for the unique row?

Comment: @Windstorm1981Sorry for the bad naming, the row_idx will only contain index for duplicated rows, unique rows will be ignored.